# How to check that no users are logged in with C# on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7

I'm using C# Windows Forms.  Is there an easy way to check if there are no users logged in?

Below is the code I've used for XP, which doesn't seem to work under windows 7 when a user is logged out.

> ```
>     private bool LoggedInUser()
>     {
>         bool loggedIn = true;
>         Process[] aProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
>         if (aProc.Length <= 0)
>         {
>             loggedIn = false;
>         }
>         return loggedIn;
>     }
> ```

Thanks :)

[edit]: The program is executed by the task scheduler, not by a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) library to see the active logon sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can p/invoke the Win32 API [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833(VS.85).aspx) / [WTSEnumerateSessionsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621014(v=VS.85).aspx) to get a listing of all of the current sessions.  I think you would only have a session 0 if there are no logged on users on Vista and Win7.  A better way to check via this method though is to check the username parameter `pUserName` from the Ex variant.

Alternatively (and probably more easily) you could use [WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835(v=VS.85).aspx) and check for a return result or `0xFFFFFFFF`.

```
//Supported for XP and up
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

public static bool HasLoggedInUsers()
{
   uint result = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
   return result != 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Hmm...this one didn't work.  The app is executed from the task scheduler with a user account while nobody is logged in.  I had it write the boolean output to a text file, and it always shows as true (somebody is logged in).  Ideas?

Comment: @Force Flow: Please print out the active console session id.  What is it?

Comment: It seems to be spitting out the number 2.

Comment: @Force then you probably have a session which has a logged on user.

Comment: @Force: Is your program running as a service? Does that service have allow service to interact with desktop enabled? Does it provide a username and a password?

Comment: Nope, not running as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerating for the `explorer.exe` was always flawed, not only in Windows 7. An user session does not necessarily require explorer.exe to be the default shell, so the process named explorer may well be not runnig. And enumerating processes require privileges a normal C# Windows forms application does not held.

The proper way to find user session is to enumerate them via [`LsaEnumerateLogonSessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378275%28VS.85%29.aspx). Another alternative is to use WMI and interogate the [`Win32_LogonSession`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394189%28VS.85%29.aspx) class.

Comment: What about fast-switching user - would that imply there's two explorer.exe processes?

Comment: How would I get started using LsaEnumerateLogonSessions?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you cannot run a program like that because the program is running and activated while a user is logged in!

Think about the old Windows 2000/XP logging process which uses [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543(VS.85).aspx) (Graphical Identification and authentication) in which when the login credentials are verified, it spawns the process Explorer which in turn activates startup and run-once applications upon logging in.

The Login process is now updated and revamped. The only way you can find out about the current sessions is in the unmanaged code perspective, a process that runs *before* the login credentials dialog box....